# Div falling out of position on rotate

Tags: html, css

I have made an analogue clock like so that shares 1 parent `div` space with 2 other `divs`:

```css
.left {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 27%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#picLeft {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16.7%;
}

.clock {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hands {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hands-cl {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 52.2%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.picRight {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-logo">
  <div class="left">
    <img id="picLeft" src="TIDleft.png">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="clock">
      <img class="hands" src="TidClockFace.png">
      <img id="hourHand" class="hands-cl" src="hourHand.png">
      <img id="minuteHand" class="hands-cl" src="hourHand.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img class="picRight" src="TIDright.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what happens:

[image]

As You can see it looks ridiculous.
I don't know if the problem is in the rotation or the image size since the `divs` shrink the images to fit the part of the website.
This is the third day I have been persistently searching for the answer. No stackoverflow threads are similar, and I have run out of ideas for search terms.
I hope this question is asked properly, and enough info has been given.
If not though, don't hesitate to ask for something or correct me.

Comment: It is not very clear what the problem is. The hands seem off-center, but this can be due to a problem in the hand image (which you have not included in the example here). The clock face itself is not precisely square, likely because you set its width to something that might not translate to an integer - but this isn't a problem, really. The html/css code that you have included doesn't show how you rotate the clock hands. If you use the style `transform: rotate(XXdeg)`, this works perfectly, provided that your hands' image is square and has the hand placed exactly in the center of the image.

Comment: I rotate them using transform rotate but didnt included it in the question because it seemed just too much. the suspicious thing is that when i enter dev tools in chrome to see actually how the whole “hand” div is rotating it changes its width and height for some reason, and the original proportions of the images are the same, could it be because of the resize, but shouldnt the size be inherited according to their respective parent divs? If the div shrinks to say 50x50 so the images should and in that way keep the position? @LeoK

Comment: by 'hand div', did you mean 'hand image'? I assume you rotate <img id="hourHand">. The image **will** change its 'rendered' size (that's measured as the extent of the rotated image left-to-right and top-to-bottom) - for a square it can grow up to 1.41 times. The rotated image will 'step' on things outside of the original box due to the rotation, but that shouldn't matter if it is transparent. Just in case, try adding 'overflow: hidden' to the surrounding div, so that anything that "sticks out" is clipped.

Comment: minor notes: (a) you're using the same image for hour and minute hands (probably not what you wanted). (b) the rendered clock face image you posted isn't 50x50, it is 1 pixel narrower than its height. This shouldn't affect severely the rotation, though. Can you share links to the actual images - or at least tell me what their true sizes are (for all of them, including TIDleft/TIDright!) so I can try out the code as intended and see what the problem might be.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I meant hand image. So if their parent div isn’t proportionally shrunk they will rotate disproportionally, or am I mistaken? As long as I keep a perfect square it should be working properly? @LeoK

Comment: Okay so all of the clock images are 224x224 natural, but when they are shrunk they are as follows: hands-86x96, clockFace-86x91. The other 2 are in original:tidLeft- 392x224, tidRight-600x180(had to do it like this because its the longest image and when shrunk the height was lower then the rest); when shrunk tidLeft is 139x84 and tidRight is 269x86. And the hands are deliberately the same, not by mistake, for testing the centering :D @LeoK

Comment: Works perfectly, if **only** the quoted code + CSS is placed in an html file (I used blank images for everything except the hand, which I made transparent with a circle and line, so I can see placement and rotation). Some additional style you have on the page is likely affecting it (margins, padding, etc.).

Comment: could it be the changing of the width and height? not being a perfect square? this conversation is in my mind pointing out to that...I have to maintain a perfect square for all of the images? sorry for the late response @LeoK

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174192/discussion-between-leo-k-and-microdev).